# Why doesn't grepl return true in grepl(".*", LETTERS, fixed=T)?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I expected this code to return a vector of 26 `TRUE` but it returns all `FALSE` instead.

```
grepl(".*", LETTERS, fixed=T)
```

From the documentation, "grepl returns a logical vector (match or not for each element of x)".

`".*"` is a match for anything so shouldn't it return all `TRUE` because it matches each letter? Tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: `.` matches more chars than just letters. It matches any character in a TRE regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know, but given that it does match letters, shouldn't it match?

Comment: See the answer below. You were looking for `.*`, not for any char.

Comment: Have a look at this [pdf](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwix3Y3c0cTVAhViCcAKHa4MBGYQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbiostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu%2Fwiki%2Fpub%2FMain%2FSvetlanaEdenRFiles%2FregExprTalk.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFIyUskVv2d4_-qJZmJyjW8fTALdw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to remove `fixed = TRUE`

```
grepl(".*", LETTERS)
```

as `fixed = TRUE` implies that the `.` and `*` are literal characters that will be available in the string.  Here, in `LETTERS`, we don't have any `.` or `*`.  These are metacharacters which imply `.` (any character), `*` (0 or more characters)

Comment: Okay, does fixed mean it ignores all regex symbols? That's not how I interpreted it after looking at other questions. I've read the help file.

Comment: @Holly `fixed = TRUE` matches the literal character i.e for example `grepl(".*", c(".*T", ".F*"), fixed = TRUE)` gives TRUE for first and FALSE for second because the `*` follows the `.` in the first case and not in the second